# opentok-android-sdk-ui sample app not working

Tags: android, android-studio, opentok

I downloaded opentok/opentok-android-sdk-ui application for text-chat from github.

I open this app in android studio. After compilation of application, it gives compilation error.That is,

> Error:Failed to resolve: :opentok-android-sdk-ui-1.0:

In Build.Gradle file it defines dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile (name: 'opentok-android-sdk-ui-1.0', ext:'aar')
}
```

How could i resolve this issue? Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You must find opentok-android-sdk-ui-1.0.aar file in opentok-android-sdk-ui-1.0/text-chat/build/outputs/aar. What you need to do is, Open Android Studio, go to File>Import Module> select the aar file from the directory. You will see that a module is created in your workspace. Now, in the project text-chat-sample, open app/build.gradle file and instead of this line

```
compile (name: 'opentok-android-sdk-ui-1.0', ext:'aar')
```

write:

```
compile project(':opentok-android-sdk-ui-1.0')
```